# how do i remove posts from a WP_Query so the pagination is right?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query, loop

I'm using a custom post type and showing 20 of them per page on the homepage. I'm using QP_Query.

One custom field for the custom post type (called mixtapes) is a checkbox called "unreleased" (set to true/false), and its basically a post that i dont want to include in the loop.

So far I put a conditional if inside the while loop to display only if 'unreleased' isnt set to 'true', but the problem is its (obviously) not applying to the loop itself, so as a result... the pagination 'sees' 40 posts (2 pages) when really theres only 1 unreleased album (which should be 1 page, but 2 pages show up). on the 2nd page, is no results.

Likewise when i want to show the 'top 10' albums which ARE released, it actually shows only 9 because the one unreleased one hasnt been removed from the actual loop, only conditionally 'hidden' after the fact.

How might i work this out so the loop keeps track of the posts that have been removed given a certain custom_field condition?

Thnkas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than querying all posts and then only displaying those that match the criteria, query for posts that match the criteria. [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) allows you to do just that with its [meta-key/meta-value](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) attributes.

For instance, to get posts where the custom field `unreleased` is to 'false', somewhere before the loop:

```
global $wp_query;
$customField = array( 'meta_key' => 'unreleased', 'meta_value' => 'false' );
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query,$customField);
query_posts( $args );
```

This isn't the most effecient way of doing things, but it is the simplest. We merge to the meta key/value query with the existing query (this includes pagination arguments).

You'll have to decide if `WP_Query` and [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Preserving_Existing_Query_Parameters) is the right thing to use here (if it's *not* the main query on the page then you should get using [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) instead - it accepts the same parameters).

Note: If you decide to use `get_posts` or `WP_Query` (but not with `query_posts` which alters the *main* query) then you shouldn't be merging. (If you're not sure which you should be using see this, now officially, ['great answer'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755) :D)

Comment: thanks!! by the way.. i thought wp_query was used for not the main loop. is that incorrect? is both wp_query and query_posts used for only the main loop and get_posts is any other type

Comment: one problem... im already using meta_key to sort by the number of views assigned to each mixtape. can i use both meta keys in the same loop?

Comment: $mixtapes = new WP_Query ( array
    ( 'post_type' => 'mixtapes', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'views' ) 
  );

Comment: See this [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) (there is a subsection on multiple custom field handling). I've not tested, but `meta_query` should be able to be used alongside `meta_key` and (certainly) `orderby`.

Comment: Yes `$wp_query` and `query_posts` refer to the main loop. `$wp_query` is an `WP_Query` object. You can have other `WP_Query` objects though (i.e. other loops), but the 'main' loop will always be `$wp_query`.